# Remove Xcode "incompatible type" type warning for subclassed properties containing subclasses

Tags: objective-c, xcode, subclass, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

Class A defines the property "items" as an ordered set containing instances of class X.

Class B subclasses A, and redefines the "items" property as an ordered set containing instances of class Y, a subclass of X.

```
// Defined in class A
@property NSOrderedSet<__kindof X *> *items;

// Defined in class B
@property NSOrderedSet<__kindof Y *> *items;
```

All Y's are a kind of X's so the subclassed property should be valid, however Xcode generates the following warning within class B:

```
Property type 'NSOrderedSet<__kindof Y *> *' is incompatible with type 'NSOrderedSet<__kindof X *> *' inherited from 'A'
```

Am I actually doing something wrong or is this an Xcode bug? How can I remove this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say that this is a bug, because it is a subject of discussions whether such a subclassing of parameters in a subclass is correct or wrong. Applying [Liskov's substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) it has to be possible to add an item of `X` to the set, because the base class allows this.Then it is an infringement of the principle, if the subclass forbids it.

However, you should remember that the "typing" of collections was introduced with Swift and was motivated to give the Swift compiler more type information. It likes that.

It is akin of anti-conceptual in pure Objective-C. Simply omit it, if you do not want to use the class from Swift.

To give you an example that is more simple. Having:

```
@interface BaseValue : NSObject
…
@end

@interface Subvalue : BasValue
- (void)anotherMethod;
…
@end

@interface BaseHolder : NSObject
@property NSMutableSet<BaseValue*>* values;
@end

@interface Subholder : BaseHolder 
@property NSMutableSet<Subvalue*>* values;
@end
```

In this example, the members of the set are restricted to be instances of `Subvalue`. Therefore the code inside `Subholder` – and any code explicitly dealing with instances of `Subholder` can expect, that the items inside the set can receive a message with the selector `anotherMethod`.

But if you do this

```
BaseValue *baseValue = [BaseValue new];
BaseHolder *baseHolder = [Subholder new]; // Get an instance of *Subholder*. The assignment is allowed by Liskov … As long as Subholder introduces no additional constraints.
[baseHolder.values addObject:baseValue]; // From the compiler's point of view legal, because you said nothing about a subclass
```

This breaks, because at runtime it is an instance of `Subholder`, but it has a member in its collection that does not match the constraint.

Comment: I think you've got the hierarchy order wrong. No property may ever contradict the conditions of its superclass, however it can add more conditions. There are no errors or warnings if class A defines an **NSString** property and class B redefines it as an **NSMutableString**, because **NSMutableString** is an **NSString**.

Comment: I'm led to believe this is an Xcode bug because this behaviour is not consistent with **NSOrderedSet** conditions.

Comment: No, I do not think that I got the hierarchy wrong. Simply think of a reference to the base class pointing to a subclass at runtime. The compiler would let you add an item of the base class to the collection, but the subclass would forbid it. Your constraint breaks very easily. It is not meaningful then.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for subclasses, because mutable containers are implemented as subclasses, what is a problem with Liskov, too. The alternative would be to have a generic base class and two subclasses. However, it is as it is and as a consequence they have to allow subclasses. (BTW: It is allowed even between interface and implementation for this reason.) But this is a different situation coming up from the very beginning of Cocoa.

Comment: I’m unclear on what you mean. The principle you referenced states that any subtype may be given in place of its supertype. I’m not using class clusters, and never have pointers to the base class referenced as a subclass. Subclass may reject types that are not the types of or subtypes of the type it specified, even if the superclass may accept them. By the way, Xcode doesn’t give any warnings for **NSOrderedSet<NSString \*> \*** being redefined as **NSOrderedSet<NSMutableString \*> \***.

Comment: This is not the problem The problem is, that your subtype introduces a *new* restriction (the class of the members of the set is restricted to a subclass) the base class does not have. From the compiler's point of view it is okay to add a member of the base class as long as you have a reference to the base class, even the pointee is an instance of a subclass. Added an example.

Comment: Thank you for the example, now I understand the potential problem. Is there a way to tell Xcode that I'm a responsible coder who wouldn't do that?

Comment: Yes, simply do, what we did decades of years before somebody came around to tell us to type everything to get back into the 70ies. Omit the generic typing: `NSOrderedSet *items`. Then the compiler would not complain, you get the freedom of dynamic typing, but has to care yourself. (Likely you implement the KVC methods for this property and do some checking with whatever result you want to implement.)